# Capture opening but not the closing tag

Tags: javascript, html, regex, regex-lookarounds, capturing-group

I want to segment a parent block, while capturing nested tags along each segment's text:

```
(?<tag>.)(?: href="(?<url>.+?)")?>(?<text>.+?)<
```

it works, but I want the "tag" to be empty in segments that aren't wrapped in a tag, however with the current reg., these capture the preceding segment's closing tag...

Live sample: https://regex101.com/r/UEZAaw/3/

The result set I would like to obtain, note that item 2 and 4 should have `null` for the tag:

```
{
   "0":{
      match: "p>The <",
      tag: "p",
      url: null,
      text: "The "
   },
   "1":[
      match: "a href=\"https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/23/contents\">UK Bribery Act<",
      tag: "a",
      url: "https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2010/23/contents",
      text: "UK Bribery Act"
   ],
   "2":[
      match: "/a> (“the Act”) received Royal Assent in April 2010 and came into ... <",
      tag: null
      url: null,
      text: " (“the Act”) received Royal Assent in April 2010 and came into ... "
   ],
   "3":[
      match: "a href=\"http://www.oecd.org/daf/anti-bribery/ConvCombatBribery_ENG.pdf\">OECD anti-bribery Convention<",
      tag: "a",
      url: "http://www.oecd.org/daf/anti-bribery/ConvCombatBribery_ENG.pdf",
      text: "OECD anti-bribery Convention"
   ],
   "4":[
      match: "/a>. The Act outlined four prime offences, including the introduction ... <",
      tag: null,
      url: null,
      text: ". The Act outlined four prime offences, including the introduction ... "
   ],
   "5":[
      match: "b>rest is history<",
      tag: "b",
      url: null,
      text: "rest is history"
   ]
   ...
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: can you give examples on what to capture and what not to capture?

Comment: You've given your attempt as well as the sample text. However you have not given an example of what you want to get (I think this is in line with what @Addis commented already). Plus, I personally find the part _but I want [...] :(_ a bit convoluted. Can you dedicate more words to your intent? Finally, why should we care about the sample markup? How is it important to the question/answers?

Comment: Does it have to be regex? It generally isn't a very good tool for XML/HTML parsing, but browsers have some amazing JavaScript tools including the DOM and [XMLDocument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLDocument) for exactly that purpose.

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I have updated the question by including a result which I would like to get. I wanted to include a source markup sample as well, which indeed, has sense only with a result sample.

Comment: @David784 It has to be, I use this for my HTML to pdf parser.

Comment: @EdmondTamas, I've still almost no clue how you use (or plan to use) `tag`, `url`, & Co., but what about `((?<tag>(?<!\/).)|(?:.))` istead of `(?<tag>.)`? This is just like capturing and naming the group or not capturing at all depending on wheter `.` is preceded by `/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this works, based on what I see in the *MATCH INFORMATION* box on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/mM78Sk/1):

```
/(?:(?<tag>(?<!\/).)|(?:\/.))(?: href="(?<url>.+?)")?>(?<text>.+?)</gm
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this works. There's only one caveat, it uses negative lookbehind which is not supported by Safari :( Do could you suggest an approach without it?

Comment: @EdmondTamas, I can't think of a way, the reason being: if you don't want to look behind (i.e. matching something without consuming it) for what precedes the tag, then you have to consume it; however, if you consume a `<` (which is what the lookbehind matches without consuming), it will not be available for the next match.